# OpenIdConnectProtocol.ValidatedIdToken.Payload.Nonce was not null - Azure AD, OpenIDConnect, C#, asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, openid-connect, katana

For some reason I am receiving the following error after attempting to redeem my auth code for an access token:

> Error: IDX21323: RequireNonce is '[PII is hidden]'. OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.Nonce was null, OpenIdConnectProtocol.ValidatedIdToken.Payload.Nonce was not null. The nonce cannot be validated. If you don't need to check the nonce, set OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator.RequireNonce to 'false'. Note if a 'nonce' is found it will be evaluated.

I'm running on IIS Express.  OWIN startup.cs as follows:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            // Sets the ClientId, authority, RedirectUri as obtained from web.config
            ClientId = clientId,
            ClientSecret = clientSecret,
            Authority = authority,
            RedirectUri = redirectUri,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
            Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
            RedeemCode = true,
            ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code,

            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidateIssuer = false,
            },
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
            },
        }
    );
}
```

As far as I am aware the middleware manages the process and I simply instruct the middleware providing a bunch of config.  I would like help to understand the error and try to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using the nuget package manager to update all related packages to the newest versions seems to have made this issue go away.